# ViewScoped bean being initialized multiple times with includeViewParams="true"

Tags: jsf, wildfly, cdi, omnifaces, mojarra

I'm currently migrating an web application developed in JSF from Wildfly 26 to Wildfly28.
All the code was refactored to `jakarta.*` and I'm experiencing some strange behaviour with `ViewScoped` beans.

On pages containing `<h:link ... includeViewParams="true"/>` the corresponding backing bean is being initialized multiple times.

#### Page Bean

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.Serializable;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Named;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class PageOne implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String page = null;

    private String search = null;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        System.out.println("Page One PostConstruct");
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return "pageTwo";
    }

    public String getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(String page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public String getSearch() {
        return search;
    }

    public void setSearch(String search) {
        this.search = search;
    }

}
```

#### Page One XHTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:f="jakarta.faces.core"
        xmlns:ui="jakarta.faces.facelets"
        xmlns:h="jakarta.faces.html"
        xmlns:a="jakarta.faces.passthrough">

    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="page" value="#{pageOne.page}" />
        <f:viewParam name="search" value="#{pageOne.search}" />
    </f:metadata>

    <body>
        <main>
            <div>
                <h:link value="#{pageOne.value}" outcome="pageTwo?faces-redirect=true" includeViewParams="true" />
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Page Two XHTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:f="jakarta.faces.core"
        xmlns:ui="jakarta.faces.facelets"
        xmlns:h="jakarta.faces.html"
        xmlns:a="jakarta.faces.passthrough">

    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="page" value="#{pageOne.page}" />
        <f:viewParam name="search" value="#{pageOne.search}" />
    </f:metadata>

    <body>
        <main>
            <div>Page Two</div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

When accessing page one, the page bean is instanciated multiple times.

The same code works as expected on Wildfly 26 (only one instance is created).

Even using `@org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped` annotation, the issue remains.

Has anyone ever had a similar issue?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have an f:view defined somewhere?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, no I don't have any f:view defined. The example is exactly as posted. Nothing was ommited.

Comment: I would try defining a view around page1 and page2 first. I’m not sure if that’s the root cause, but it seems very strange to be using jsf without defining views.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I tried your suggestion and it makes no difference. The problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed on Mojarra 4.0.3

Tested successfully on Wildfly 29.0.0 Final after updating Mojarra from 4.0.2 to 4.0.3

https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/5290